DRF: The registration token is not a valid FCM registration token in the first time i send noti
After technical login, the first notification will return the same response
enter image description here
But from the time I sent it onwards, everything was fine
enter image description here
This is my scripts
class SendServiceOrderView(APIView):
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = SendServiceOrderSerializer(data=request.data)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        service_order, technicians, invalid_technician_ids = self.get_order_data(serializer)
        devices = FCMDevice.objects.filter(user__in=technicians)
        service_order_data = service_order_service.get_by_id(service_order)
        serialized_order = FBServiceOrderSerializer(service_order_data)

        response_data = self.send_notifications(devices, serialized_order.data)
        response_data["failed_technical_ids"] = list(invalid_technician_ids.union(
            set(technicians.values_list('id', flat=True)) - set(devices.values_list('user_id', flat=True))
        ))
        return Response(response_data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK if devices else status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)

    def get_order_data(self, serializer):
        return (
            serializer.validated_data['service_order'],
            serializer.validated_data['technicians'],
            serializer.validated_data['invalid_technician_ids']
        )

    def send_notifications(self, devices, order_data):
        
        response_data = {"message": "Notification sent to %d devices." % devices.count()}
        if devices:
            try:
                for device in devices:
                    device.send_message(Message(
                        token=device.user.fcm_token,
                        notification=Notification(
                            title='Find new work',
                            body=order_data['service']['name']
                        ),
                        data = {
                            "data": json.dumps(order_data)
                        }
                    ))
            except Exception as e:
                response_data["errors"] = str(e)
        else:
            response_data["message"] = "No valid devices found for the specified technicians."
        return response_data

I hope the first's reponse same the second
